# combining stock images and footage

Tags: copyright, licensing

If I license stock images/video footage from a stock image company and alter and recombine them in a layered composition with my own original elements added to create a new image/video composed of many images/videos, do I then own the copyright to the final product?

Answer (score 1):

You would, unless your license agreement for the images said otherwise, or prohibited you from making such a combined work at all. The licenses for stock images that I have encountered make copyright in the derived work the property of the user, provided that that work is not simply a republication of the stock image.